# Не отображается система при подключении монитора по DVI-D

Tags: экран

Я подключил два ПК к одному монитору, у которого сзади есть два входа: DVI-D и HDMI. С HDMI никогда никаких проблем не было. Но если отображать изображение через DVI-D, то его максимум это заставка материнки и биос. Дальше черный экран, хотя компьютер работает исправно. В чем заключается проблема?

Comment: У самого монитора в меню разве нет выбора входа, с которого он сигнал берёт? Он, конечно, и автоматом наверное должен понимать, где есть сигнал, но не всегда это работает.

Comment: Да, на панели есть такая кнопка. Поэтому и спрашиваю, какие могут быть причины того, что при переключении на DVI дальше биоса не идет, а на HDMI все нормально?

Comment: Так, а в самом биосе нет ли каких опций на эту тему? А то смутно помню что-то такое, что ещё и там надо было выбрать что-то.

Comment: В биосе, во вкладке «internal graphics» было выставлено auto, поставил на enable (в компе который по dvi подключён нет видеокарты). Заставку системы показало, и дальше опять тьма